# Camel decoding UTF-8 characters (greek symbols) as '?'s

Tags: java, rest, utf-8, apache-camel, rest-assured

When making a http request to my REST service with greek characters, the response replaces them with question marks. An example making a request with REST assured:

```
// test unicode redirect
    String greekText = "Ξεσκεπάζω τὴν ψυχοφθόρα βδελυγμία";

    expect()
        .statusCode(302)
        .header(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, is("http://foo.bar?winning=" + greekText))
    .given()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .redirects().follow(false)
        .cookies(cookies).log().all()
        .param("placeRef", greekText)
        .param("loc", "http://foo.bar?winning={{tmplaceref}}")
    .when()
        .get("/{client}", "client9");
```

This produces the error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
Expected header "Location" was not is "http://foo.bar?winning=Ξεσκεπάζω τὴν ψυχοφθόρα βδελυγμία", was "http://foo.bar?winning=????????? ??? ????????? ?????????". Headers are:
```

I'm using Apache Camel and was wondering if anyone had seen a similar issue before?

Comment: Non-ASCII (and reserved) characters in a URL have to be charset-encoded and percent-encoded. The real URL would look more like `http://foo.bar?winning=%CE%9E%CE%B5%CF%83%CE%BA%CE%B5%CF%80%CE%AC%CE%B6%CF%89%20%CF%84%E1%BD%B4%CE%BD%20%CF%88%CF%85%CF%87%CE%BF%CF%86%CE%B8%CF%8C%CF%81%CE%B1%20%CE%B2%CE%B4%CE%B5%CE%BB%CF%85%CE%B3%CE%BC%CE%AF%CE%B1`, ie your greek text encoded in UTF-8 and then each byte octet encoded in `%HH` format.  BTW, shouldn't `{tmplaceref}` be `{placeRef}`?